# Issue with Remove Application Role in AzureAD using GraphAPI / C#

Tags: c#, api, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to Add/Remove Application Role in AzureAD using VisualStudio/C#/GraphAPI. I can successfully add user to ApplicationRole but Remove(or Delete) role doesn't work.

I researched on internet and it seems an issue with AzureAD graph API itself. check:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5707763c-41f7-4465-abdb-3a8d8ded153b/graph-api-apiversion15-how-to-remove-user-from-application-role-using-c-net?forum=WindowsAzureAD

However, it's an old post so not sure if any workaround is available now.

Any help is appreciated to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I can successfully add user to ApplicationRole but Remove(or Delete) role doesn't work.

I can remove the application role with follow code.

```
var listRoles = user.AppRoleAssignments.ToList();
user.AppRoleAssignments.Remove(listRoles[0]); //just demo: you could remove the role as your wanted
user.UpdateAsync().Wait();
```

The following is my detail test demo code

1.get access token

```
private static async Task<string> GetAppTokenAsync(string graphResourceId, string tenantId, string clientId, string secretKey)
        {
            string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/token";
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance, false);
            var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId,
                new ClientCredential(clientId, userId));
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
```

2.Init the graphclient.

```
var graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientId = "client Id";
var secretKey = "secret key";
var servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId); 
var serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);
var activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await GetAppTokenAsync(graphResourceId, tenantId, clientId, secretKey));
```

3.create application and service principal

```
 Application appObject = new Application { DisplayName = "Test-Demo App" };
 appObject.IdentifierUris.Add("https://localhost/demo/" + Guid.NewGuid());
 appObject.ReplyUrls.Add("https://localhost/demo");
 AppRole appRole = new AppRole
 {
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    IsEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = "Something",
    Description = "Anything",
    Value = "policy.write"
 };

 appRole.AllowedMemberTypes.Add("User");
 appObject.AppRoles.Add(appRole);
 activeDirectoryClient.Applications.AddApplicationAsync(appObject).Wait();
 // create a new Service principal
 ServicePrincipal newServicePrincpal = new ServicePrincipal
 {
    DisplayName = appObject.DisplayName,
    AccountEnabled = true,
    AppId = appObject.AppId
 };
activeDirectoryClient.ServicePrincipals.AddServicePrincipalAsync(newServicePrincpal).Wait();
```

4.add role assginments

```
User user = (User) activeDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId("userobjectId").ExecuteAsync().Result;
AppRoleAssignment appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment
{
       Id = appRole.Id,
       ResourceId = Guid.Parse(newServicePrincpal.ObjectId),
       PrincipalType = "User",
       PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(user.ObjectId),

  };
user.AppRoleAssignments.Add(appRoleAssignment);
user.UpdateAsync().Wait();
```

5.remove the role from user

```
var listRoles = user.AppRoleAssignments.ToList();
user.AppRoleAssignments.Remove(listRoles[0]);
user.UpdateAsync().Wait();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. May I know which version of Graph API library you are using ? Because It seems Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient version 2.1.1 has known issue to remove Application Role

Comment: For me, user.AppRoleAssignments comes 0 (zero), but this user does have an Application Role

Comment: I am using below code to remove App role, which doesn't give any error, but doesn't remove role either>

Comment: IUserFetcher u = user;

    var appRoleAssignmentResult = await u.AppRoleAssignments.Where(a => a.ResourceId == servicePrincipalId).ExecuteAsync();

var existingRoleAssignment = (AppRoleAssignment)appRoleAssignmentResult.CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault();

if (existingRoleAssignment != null)
{
 user.AppRoleAssignments.Remove(existingRoleAssignment); 

 user.UpdateAsync().Wait();
}

Comment: `user.AppRoleAssignments comes 0 (zero), but this user does have an Application Role` What does that mean? And would you mind sharing how to check that.